# Disable 3rd party keyboard for specific UITextField in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, custom-keyboard, disable

I have a requirement wherein I need to disable the 3rd party keyboards (ex Gboard from google) from showing up in UI when specific set of UITextField is focused. I need to do this for sensitive input fields like email field, credit card field.

From documentation, I was able to implement the following code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: UIApplication.ExtensionPointIdentifier) -> Bool {

        if extensionPointIdentifier == .keyboard {

            if vc.dontShowCustomKeyboard {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

I am returning false if the view controller has boolean which says not to use custom keyboard. But some time I do see custom key board showing up even though I am returning bool. This works correct for the first time. After that if I go to other controller, tap on any text field in that controller (assume that it supports custom keyboard) and come back and select the field in the 1st controller, the custom keyboard shows up.

I'm not sure why it is happening. Did anyone has any inputs please do share. Thank you.